# mkdir falsely complains no such directory on mounted volumne

Tags: command-line, permissions, mount

I am attempting to create a directory on mounted volume `M2` but mkdir is failing. I suspect this is a permissions issue, but the listed file permissions are all rwx. I have tried `chown -R me M2/` but that did not solve the issue. Possibly relevant is that I am dual booting and though there are no system or user files on this drive, I did write most or all of the existing data to this drive from windows. OS version 20.04. Output is as follows:

```
(base) me@me-ub:/M2$ ls -la
total 3993
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root   28672 Oct 24 12:50  .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root    4096 Feb 10  2021  ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root       0 Jan 16  2022 '$RECYCLE.BIN'
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root   16384 Oct 18  2021  stu
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root   12288 Oct  2  2021  pucks
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root 1466368 Oct 26  2021  Camera
...
```

It appears that the files on this drive are almost all read-only, however I was able to create a new directory one level down in one of the existing dirs. What should I do?

Comment: Is the drive really mounted, and is it read-write-mounted? (do `mount | grep M2` to find out.)

Comment: @Jos output reads `/dev/nvme0n1p2 on /M2 type fuseblk (rw, ...`, I assume rw is read-write?

Comment: All of the directories in `/M2` are writeable (by an ordinary user), but the directory `/M2` itself is probably not writable, which you can verify by doing `ls -la /`, or looking at the top line with the `.` directory. From the `drwxr-xr-x` permissions, you would need to be the owner (`root`) of `/M2`. That explains why you can create a directory one level down, but not in `/M2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by dual booting with fast startup enabled on windows. Disabling fast startup solved the problem.